# How to cut MPEG and H.264 files frame-accurately without re-encoding?

Tags: editing, lossless

Occasionally, the video-files need to be cut to keep only the relevant parts. Thus, how does one go about cutting the common video files (H.264, MPEG) without any re-encoding and thus quality loss?

Answer (score 4):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) is the perfect tool for this. It's also free, open source and available for Windows, macOS and Linux.

H.264 and H.265 encoded videos have certain complete frames (**keyframes**) that are called **I-frames** or **Intra Frames**.

To ensure that you don't have to re-encode a video when you delete some some portions of it, just make sure that you select and delete the portion of video *between* two **I-frames**.

Avidemux makes finding keyframes or I-Frames very easy - just open the video in it, and use the <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> arrow keys to move between keyframes. To select a portion of video between keyframes, use the <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> arrow keys on your keyboard to find the first keyframe of the video portion, and click the **`[A`** button on AviDemux. Then use the <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> arrow keys to again move to the final key frame of the video portion, and click the **`][B`** button on Avidemux. This will select the portion of video between the 2 keyframes.

You can now either delete this portion or click save to just extract and save this portion of the video. No re-encoding will be done.

More information on how to cut or extract videos on Avidemux can be read here - [Simple cutting on Avidemux](https://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using:cutting).

Comment: Upvoted, thanks for sharing info!

Comment: Thanks. If this answered your question, please also mark it as the *accepted* answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer (below the downvote arrow). See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn more.

Comment: Hey @sfxedit , you miss the point! Much of thew lossless information is obscure, and the point of question is not to have the 'best' answer but to collect information in one place. If there's going to be an even better answer (or perhaps my answer may be better) - then why should it be less 'accepted'?

Comment: @tabdiukov The primary manner SE works is the question and answer format. If somebody posts a better answer, you can mark that as the accepted answer later. But from what you have described, what you desire is a *community wiki*. (See [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). For this, you should make a request here https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/ and if the mods are satisfied they can convert this post to a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Solution does NOT work with H.265

One solution that has proven to be stable and fast over the years is to use [Fame-Ring Smart.Cutter](https://www.fame-ring.com/smart_cutter.html). The software is natively designed to perform frame-perfect cuts without quality loss or re-encoding.

It is recommended to disable "audio VU meter" in program settings to improve stability, ([learn more](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/391669-Trying-to-use-Smart-Cutter-for-1920x1080-video#post2580152))

Ever since Windows 7, the [software is reported to crash, especially when seeking too fast](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/331916-Smart-Cutter-for-DV-and-DVB-crashes). It's possible to avoid crashes either by seeking slowly or by using an XP VM.